# Apache Felix the DOSGI single bundle and Zookeeper

Tags: java, web-services, hadoop, osgi, apache-felix

I am trying to implement LAN based service discovery in my project. I have Apache Felix with the DOSGI single bundle distribution deployed. Additionally, I have the Apache Hadoop Zookeeper server running. i have been following this tutorial [here](http://cxf.apache.org/dosgi-discovery.html)

However, i dont know what it means when it says

> To configure the ZooKeeper client in CXF/Discovery the following configuration variables apply. They need to be set on Configuration Admin PID org.apache.cxf.dosgi.discovery.zookeeper.

it then says

> An easy way to set the configuration, it by placing a file called org.apache.cxf.dosgi.discovery.zookeeper.cfg in the load directory created by the FileInstall bundle with the following content:
>   zookeeper.host = 127.0.0.1

the problem im having is that i cant find the load directory that the FileInstall bundle is supposed to create. I need this to complete my final year project and am running out of time

any help on this is much appreciated

Many thanks

Billy

Answer (score 0):

You should create the `load` directory yourself. You can even configure it to point to a different directory if you like. More information about that can be found in the documentation of Apache Felix File Install: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-file-install.html

If you're after LAN based service discovery, then you might want to consider using different discovery protocols (like for example SLP).

And, shameless plug, you might also want to take a look at Amdatu Remote, which will be the reference implementation for the updated Remote Services specification: http://amdatu.org/components/remote.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. i am using the DOSGI single bundle distribution which has the  FileInstall bundle included. I don't know how to or where to create this load directory. Do i create this load directory in the root of my apache felix folder? if I create a load directory in the root of my apache felix distribution how do i notify the file install bundle of the new watched directory??